# Passsing a value from an ASP cshtml into through js script to a controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html-table, controller, parameter-passing

**Context:**

I have ASP.NET CORE 6 project.

I have added a button into a table that displays users. This button fires a modal window that later on would have a short snippet of logic (resetting the password of the user).

**Need:**

The modal window actually fires and is working for each row, but I am not able to pass a parameter from a table's row button into a controller.

**View** (.cshtml)**:**

```
<table class="table xtable-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tablealtrow">
        @foreach (var user in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.UserName</td>
                    ...
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnShowModal">Reset Password</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

...

<div class="modal fade" id="Modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $('[id*=btnShowModal]').on("click", function () 
        {
            $.get("@Url.Action("ResetPassword","UserRoles",
                function (data) 
                { 
                    $('.modal-body').html(data); 
                })
            $("#Modal").modal('show');
        });
        $("#btnHideModal").click(function () 
        {
            $("#Modal").modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**The model:**

Probably would have a UserIdentity and UserManager instances, but for a while I make it simple.

```
public class ResetPasswordModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**The controller:**

Here I am creating a ResetPasswordModel with a dummy data, but would expect to get a user id here from the view.

```
public IActionResult ResetPassword()
{
    return PartialView("ResetPassword", new ResetPasswordModel() { Id = 1, Name="TESTTESTTEST" });
}
```

**The modal view model:**

There would be logic of resetting the password after user clicks Reset button. Also the temporary password would be displayed. I would manage this logic on my own.

```
@model ResetPasswordModel

<p>You are about to reset the password for the user: @Model.Name</p>

<a class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary">Reset</a>
```

**Already tries:**

I was not able to manage it, despite many tries. Among others:

- use `$.ajax` instead of `$.get`.
- set attribute `data-user-name="@user.UserId"` on a button
- tried to get the value somehow through the view element instance into a js variable and pass it to action:

```
    CONTROLLER:
    public IActionResult ResetPassword(string parameterUSERID)

    JS SCRIPT:
    var parameterTEST = $('#userId').val;
    var parameterTEST  = $(this).data('user-name');
    $.get("@Url.Action("ResetPassword","UserRoles", new { parameterUSERID = parameterTEST  })", ... )
```

Sorry for an amateur question like that. This is actually my first JS task.